# Recycle or pass credentials in web client

Tags: c#, webclient, credentials

I have a Webclient which works perfectly if I add the credentials in the code, however I already logged in and when I try to use DefaultCredentials (which I think is the same account I used before) I get an error:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

This works perfectly when I tried when I run it with Visual Studio, but when I publish the app it doesn't.

```
  var wb = new WebClient();
                wb.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                wb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "@domain");
```

Error when:

```
  var wb = new WebClient();
wb.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                wb.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Some Ideas?

I can use  `HttpContext.Current.User`. Can I get the credentials of it?

Comment: That uses basic authentication, if the system does not support basic authentication or form authentication, then it will not actually authorize.  We need information about your endpoint.

Comment: I have to apps in the same server, the first one askme for credentials to login, I want to use the same credentials beacuse are the same I dont want to relogin. The apps are in the same server but, different apppool/group in IIS. I even tried to add default credentias in "conect as" but doesnt work

Comment: How does that other application store the credentials?  Cookie?  Session? Encrypted Cookie? etc.?

Comment: @Greg, I dont, the login is made by Windows Account Login application pool restriction. I can use the logged account by `HttpContext.Current.User`

Comment: But not all browsers support that and default credentials is limited to NTLM, Negotiation, and Kerberos.  So if your application is not using those authentication approaches, then default credentials won't work.